# Media Query change image source not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I just have a small issue that I am hoping is a simple fix..

The webpage is just one whole image. When a user shrinks their browser window or is on a phone it will change the front image shown.

Now I have tried testing it every which way, breaking down the code. The only part not working is the **.bg** after the media query. I can change the background color dynamically so I know the media query is otherwise working. I have also gotten that source link to work so I am sure that is not the issue. Any thoughts?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>backround image</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<style type="text/css">

body{
    background-image: url("../vortex2/vortextwebsite.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.bg {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    z-index: -3;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
.bg:after {
    content: url("../vortex2/vortexWebsitesmall.jpg");
 }
body{
background-color: red
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 621px) {
.bg:after {
    content: url("../vortex2/vortextwebsite.jpg");
}
body{
background-color: white
}
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

    <img class = "bg" src="vortextwebsite.jpg" alt="Webpage Background">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just dropped your code into jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1y7stxny/ Looks pretty weird. What exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: You can't use pseudo element on single tag elements like the `img`

Comment: what is the point of your body with a background and `img` tag  with the same source? if you want to change the background you can do it in media query with your `body` tag just change the url and boom!

Comment: I ended up following the first answer by using a div instead and now changing the background using css. And K. Daniek I am  building a website with a large image background that changes on screen side. Bit of a different way to do a website but this is a slimmed down version of what I am building for easier to debug reasons. Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the content attribute of the psuedo element which has nothing that pushes it above the existing image element. If you want the image to change based on css I would suggest one of three options:

1. use a div instead and change the background using the css.
2. use a templating language to change the source of the image element.
3. have multiple image elements that hide based on css.

The first option in my opinion is the best since it requires minimal overhead and fewest extra DOM nodes.